# jQuery UI Accordion conflicting with slidebars

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently using slidebars with jQuery UI but they seem to be conflicting with each other and I can't seem to figure out what is the problem with it. The slidebars extends itself too much causing a lot of unwanted white space. I would like to know what I can do to solve this issue. Any help appreciated! Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/F2v8K/1/

```
<div class="sb-site-container" data-role="main">
   <div class="ui-mobile-nav sb-toggle-left">
        <span class="icon-menu6 ui-small-icon">Menu</span>
    </div>

<div class="ui-inner-default">
    <div id="ui-mov-accordion">
        <h3>General</h3>
        <div class="ui-default-container ui-inner-default" >
        <h2 class="ui-svc-subtitle">Rooms</h2>
            <table class="tg">
              <tr>
                <th class="tg-s6z2">Rooms</th>
                <th class="tg-s6z2">1</th>
                <th class="tg-s6z2">2</th>
                <th class="tg-s6z2">3</th>
                <th class="tg-s6z2">4</th>
                <th class="tg-s6z2">5</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="tg-s6z2">Starting Price</td>
                <td class="tg-s6z2">S$20</td>
                <td class="tg-s6z2">S$50</td>
                <td class="tg-s6z2">S$60</td>
                <td class="tg-s6z2">S$80</td>
                <td class="tg-s6z2">S$100</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
           <div class="ui-mobile-navbar sb-slidebar sb-left">
           <ul class="nav-mobile-items">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Adam, the author of Slidebars.

You don't need to use both `#sb-site` and `.sb-site-container`. The site container class was added from version 0.10 for those who didn't want to use an id.

The problem your having is occuring because your `.sb-slidebar` element, was located inside of your `.sb-site-container`. When the opening animation is triggered, its pulling the Slidebar across as well as the site.

Your site container and slidebars need to be direct children of the body tag like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="sb-site-container">
    <!-- Your main page content here -->
  </div>

  <div class="sb-slidebar sb-left">
    <!-- Your off-canvas content here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

I have updated your fiddle, and corrected it for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/xWvBL/3/

I hope that helps and glad your using the plugin :)

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 0):

There is some rather specific html needed for the plugin to work, according to the [usage docs](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/usage.php).  Your example code seems to work properly if the `sb-site` div is added around the main content:

```
<div id="sb-site">
    <div class="sb-site-container" data-role="main">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-mobile-navbar sb-slidebar sb-left">
    <ul class="nav-mobile-items">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also note that the above code must be the direct child of the body element, and that you need this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: can you make the modifications into a fiddle? I can't seem to get it working with your code above.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/xWvBL/1/ I added the `sb-site` div and moved the slidebar div to the bottom, as above.